# How to emit infrared radiation online without configuring the monitor/hardware?

Tags: infrared, camera, video

I wish to make a video streaming application where infrared radiations are emitted out of the display so that if someone tries to record the video through a camera, all they see is a white light and not the video.

Note. Let's assume the cameras don't have IR filters, though most of them do have it.

Is there some way to achieve this without configuring the display hardware ? Anything innovative or creative way to deal with this ?
Or how else do you suggest one can stop online camera recordings ?

Comment: Develop your video in [Anaglyph 3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaglyph_3D) and require the user to wear those glasses to watch. A camera recording of it will be at least semi-frustrating to some.

Answer (score 4):

You can't. The light in an LCD monitor comes from the backlight, which is a white LED (or fluorescent lamp in older monitors). The backlight does not emit infrared light; even if it did, the LCD has no way of allowing that light through.